# How to prevent an admin account with less privileges in WooCommerce to change the stock quantity of a product (prevent decrease and allow increase)

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-theming

I would like to be able to disable the "decrease button" (but allow the "increase one") in the WooCommerce admin product page.
The reason for this is that I was the person who is responsible for the products to be able to increase the stock quantity in case of new deliveries but NOT able to decrease the stock number for any product.

Do you have any ideas on how to do this?
I'm attaching a photo with the function I want to disable.

[image: 1]

I tried to find the method / function but with no success

Answer (score 0):

Those arrows are added by browser because the field is number type, you can't just remove one if them.
You could add some Javascript to trigger when the value of this field is changed and allow only increase, check my code sample.
This is not a really secure solution but I think it covers your requirement.

```
function disable_stock_decrease_button(  ) {
    ?>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('_stock').setAttribute('min', document.getElementById('_stock').value);
    </script>

<?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 'disable_stock_decrease_button', 10, 0 );
```

This action is triggered after the quantity field is created and we simply output some javascript code below the field. This javascript will set the 'min' attribute on the stock field to the initial value of that field. The browser will then stop user from decreasing the value to less than initial and if they write it manually, the validation error will be triggered.

This is not very safe solution because one could simply open dev tools and undo the change but I assume you need this to prevent accidental errors. If you need a secure solution, then you have to do the validation on the server side, after the product is saved.

Comment: Hi @Ivo Jerkovic, I tried your solution and it works perfectly when using the buttons - exactly what I wanted. But it doesn't work when you are trying to quickly modify the product and when you will write manually a value less than the initial one ...

Comment: It will let you enter the lower number but it won't let you save, the validation won't let you submit and the message will pop up above the field.
"Quick edit" is a different story, it's generated by javacript when you click the quick edit action. This means you would have to insert a javascript that will add this limit to the field every time someone clicks quick edit.

Comment: This this solution work for you?